# How to extract two rows for each unique user id

Tags: mysql

Following query used to extract the following column & rows.

issue is i am not able extract two rows from each user ID .
If i am using limit then fetches only 1st two rows.

so how i can extract the two rows for each Unique user id.

For example :

```
two rows of userid 222
two rows of userid 122
two rows of userid 367
```

and so on

TEXT OP :

Expected output :

Comment: what output you need?

Comment: Can you copy and paste the **text** output from your query into your question?

Comment: please check image link .

Comment: I asked for the **TEXT** output because I wanted to use the data, not to rekey it by hand.

Comment: check question added text output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming **id** is your user id and **post_ID** is unique.

```
(SELECT id,name,post,Image,post
    FROM users  
    GROUP BY id
    ORDER BY id
)
UNION
(SELECT id,name,post,Image,post
    FROM users
    WHERE post_ID NOT IN
    (SELECT post_ID
    FROM users  
    GROUP BY id
    ORDER BY id)
    GROUP BY id
    ORDER BY id
)
ORDER BY id, post_ID
```

---

Please check my query from which I get the below answer:

```
(
SELECT store_id, `key_id` , `string` , `translate` , `locale`
FROM `core_translate` AS C
GROUP BY `store_id`
ORDER BY `store_id`
)
UNION (

SELECT store_id, `key_id` , `string` , `translate` , `locale`
FROM `core_translate` AS C
WHERE `key_id` NOT
IN (

SELECT `key_id`
FROM `core_translate` AS C
GROUP BY `store_id`
ORDER BY `store_id`
)
GROUP BY `store_id`
ORDER BY C.`store_id`
)
ORDER BY store_id, `key_id`
```

---

```
store_id    key_id  string  translate   locale
0   20  Screensize  Screensize  en_US
0   21  Gender  Gender  en_US
1   1   Size    Size    en_US
1   2   Color   Color   en_US
2   5   Large Image     Large Image     en_US
2   6   Medium Image    Medium Image    en_US
3   10  Manufacturer    Manufacturer    en_US
3   11  Dimensions  Dimensions  en_US
4   15  Description     Description     en_US
4   16  Weight  Weight  en_US
```

Comment: using DISTINCT it is actually showing only 1st two rows. I am trying to extract two rows for every user.

Comment: Please check the modified answer.

Comment: This is a union query and it should give you 2 results for each user. Why did you get 1 row? Have you ran the whole query?

Comment: If your table doesn't have 2 rows then it will not show 2 rows :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is workable on mysql, but you can this.
I'm assuming `id` is user id and `post_ID` is unique.

**EDIT**

try to workaround mysql limitation.

```
select id,name,post_Imagename_small,Image_title,post_ID from users u1
where u1.post_ID in (
    select u3.post_ID from (
        select u2.post_ID from users u2
        where u2.id = u1.id
        limit 2
    ) s u3
)
order by u1.id
```

**EDIT 2**

in the case that the answer doesn't work, [here](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/) is a good reading on this sort of querying problem, there're various solving approachs too.

Comment: This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery' any other solution ?

Comment: Mind trying out my edit? I don't have access to any MySQL db right now.

Comment: @ASD: Which version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @Mark according to the documentation, MySQL still doesn't support this kind of query yet. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/subquery-restrictions.html