# Getting two rows after nth row for each user

Tags: sql, sql-server

My table structure:

```
consumer_id, signup_date, plan_id, subscription_date
```

It has multiple subscription_dates for the same consumer_id.

I wish to get results only for those users who have atleast two rows of data
For each user I need to get a result which gives me the top two rows ordered by subscription_date..

Then I want another set of result of all users who have atleast three rows of data..
For each user I need to get a result which gives me the top second and third rows..

and so on...

I have a feeling its something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16208353/how-to-extract-two-rows-for-each-unique-user-id) but could not get it to work in my case..

Update:

Sample table data:

```
1 1/1/2015 1 3/1/2015
2 1/1/2015 1 3/1/2015
2 1/1/2015 1 4/1/2015
3 1/1/2015 1 6/1/2015
2 1/1/2015 1 6/1/2015
3 1/1/2015 1 7/1/2015
```

Sample Output1:

```
2 1/1/2015 1 3/1/2015
2 1/1/2015 1 4/1/2015
3 1/1/2015 1 6/1/2015
3 1/1/2015 1 7/1/2015
```

Sample Output2:

```
2 1/1/2015 1 4/1/2015
2 1/1/2015 1 6/1/2015
```

Comment: Google around ROW_NUMBER.

Comment: Please provide some sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is should give you answer to your first part,But to get entire answer please let us know more details of the query (will be great if we have some output)
Note: I am assuming #test as your main table.

```
select * from 
    (
        SELECT a.consumer_id, a.signup_date, a.plan_id, a.subscription_date
        ,RANK() OVER 
        (PARTITION BY a.consumer_id ORDER BY a.subscription_date ASC) AS Rank1
        FROM #test a
        where a.consumer_id in
            (   
                select consumer_id as count from #test 
                group by consumer_id
                having count(consumer_id)>=2    
            )  
    ) as b
    where b.Rank1<=2


For the second part.


select * from #test

    select * from 
    (
        SELECT a.consumer_id, a.signup_date, a.plan_id, a.subscription_date
        ,RANK() OVER 
        (PARTITION BY a.consumer_id ORDER BY a.subscription_date ASC) AS Rank1
        FROM #test a
        where a.consumer_id in
            (   
                select consumer_id as count from #test 
                group by consumer_id
                having count(consumer_id)>=3    
            )  
    ) as b
    where b.Rank1 between 2 and 3
```

Comment: would not b.Rank1<=2 also provide the single rows if a user has only one row of data

Comment: Thanks, this should provide the result for the first output.. any ideas of the second output where I need the second and third ranked rows for all users who have atleast three rows of data.. should the changes be count(consumer_id)>=2 and where b.Rank1<=3 and b.Rank1>=2

Comment: Updated the answer, also Kindly accept the answer if it satisfies your requirement. Thanks

Comment: Honestly, Sagar Shirke, you are asking the OP to accept your answer in advance? Really? Please remember that this site is not just for you to get rep points or just for Arnab to solve their problems. Rather it's for everyone to find knowledge. Others might have alternative suggestions, which might or might not work for Arnab but it's quite probable they might work better for someone else. The problem is, when an answer is accepted, the attention to the question drops dramatically and the question is less likely to get more answers. So please be fair and patient. @Arnab, for your attention too.

Comment: @AndriyM..you are absolutely correct.. I totally agree with you..but at the same time we have to consider one thing is that there are many people in this knowledge sharing site who  ask the question then gets good answers too but never acknowledges the efforts of other contributors in any way..so to avoid that I requested to accept the answer and it is applicable just not for myself , I would be very happy if more deserving user's answer gets accepted so that other future needing person will be benefited..but surely your this suggestion and comment is appreciable..thanks.